# Google search integration in chrome extension throws a Policy Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-search

Can somebody please help me?

I am trying to use google search ready foкm in my chrome extension. I've taken it from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

When i try it not in extension everything works. In extension it throws an error.

HTML:

```
    <div class="gcse-search"></div>


Manifest: {
  "name": "Yoobinet test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
  "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "history"
    ],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "src/override/override.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cse.google.com/ https://www.google.com/cse/static/ http://clients1.google.com/complete/search  object-src 'self' "
  
}

Error: 
Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://cse.google.com/adsense/search/async-ads.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive.
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a URL that starts with `//` in your html file. Specify `https://` explicitly.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: Replace "//cse.google.com/cse.js" with `"https://cse.google.com/cse.js"` in your html file. If it doesn't help the problem is the Google's script itself - it probably doesn't work inside extension pages.